# Transformer copper loss

Tags: power, transformer, current-transformer, copper, core

In this Example the efficiency for a full-load transformer was asked to solve. The book calculated the copper losses after referral to the secondary side as the following : Pcu = (Is)^2*Req = (65.2 A)^2*(0.0445ll) = 189 W . But in the table below the Psc should indicate the copper loss at full-load also ; Hence why are the two values different from each other?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is from Electric Machiney Fundamentals, 4th Edition.
I see what is going on: the short circuit test is done by shorting the secondary coil of the transformer, not by applying a full load, because the purpose is to find the parameters of the transformer. Once the parameters are found, the magnitude of the current at full load is found by dividing the magnitude of the apparent power by the magnitude of the voltage. I believe you neglect the fact that the coil is shorted during a short circuit test and the coil is left open in an open circuit test. If the load was added in the test, it would be very messy to find the parameters.